# java.net.URLEncoder.encode(String) is deprecated, what should I use instead?

Tags: java, url, network-programming, deprecated

I get the following warning when using `java.net.URLEncoder.encode`:

```
warning: [deprecation] encode(java.lang.String)
         in java.net.URLEncoder has been deprecated
```

What should I be using instead?

Comment: This is answered in the deprecation tag in the docs: "Instead, use the encode(String,String) method to specify the encoding." See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html.

Answer (score 314, accepted):

Use the other `encode` method in [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
URLEncoder.encode(String, String)
```

The first parameter is the text to encode; the second is the name of the character encoding to use (e.g., `UTF-8`). For example:

```
System.out.println(
  URLEncoder.encode(
    "urlParameterString",
    java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()
  )
);
```

Comment: @jsh: I'm confused, why shouldn't there be a URLDecoder? Why does this make Java bloated? These are static methods. It would take the same amount of effort to type either. If you like Python, why are you programming in Java? Is it because more people use Java than Python and you got a Java job instead of Python job?

Comment: @stepanian yep, you gotta work where the work is. the python package i typically use puts all these encoding and decoding utilities under one roof.  I mainly added this comment because I had to go and find the URLDecoder and I thought it might save somebody a couple of minutes to know this was what was required.

Comment: @jsh: A lot of people like Python. I have never used it, but I'm sure I would like it too if I had the time to try it. But I am chasing the dollar too. Java ain't that bad.

Comment: He's calling it bloated because its overpopulating the global class namespace. Why have URLEncoder.encode and URLDecoder.decode when you could have URL.encode and URL.decode, or even just URLEncoder.decode? Why make it all redundant and bloaty? Because its java.

Comment: And then you have to handle the UnsupportedEncodingException, even though UTF-8 should be supported pretty much everywhere.

Comment: @tc.: Java 7 introduced these constants: `StandardCharsets.US_ASCII`, `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` etc. Unfortunately, `URLEncoder.encode` does not accept a `Charset`... (but many other moethods do).

Comment: @sleske the constant from Java 1 is **HTTP.UTF_8**

Comment: @htafoya, **wrong**. This class is found in Apache HttpClient 4.x library `org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP` class.

Comment: Minor suggestion - use `URLEncoder.encode(<urlStringToBeEncoded>, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())`.   Using the static constant `UTF_8`'s `toString()` method as the character encoding scheme throws `java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8]` as the `toString()` returns "java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8]". To get the desired "UTF-8" use its `name()` method instead.

Comment: So instead of a simple way to encode we now have a longer more painful method that throws an exception.  Why can't it just default to the lowest common denominator, it's not like I am encrypting anything.  Who ever decided on this change should take an arrow to the knee.

Answer (score 42):

You should use:

```
URLEncoder.encode("NAME", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 34):

Use the class [**URLEncoder**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

```
URLEncoder.encode(String s, String enc)
```

Where :

> **s** - String to be translated.
>
> **enc** - The name of a supported [**character encoding**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html#charenc).

**Standard charsets:**

> **US-ASCII**   Seven-bit ASCII, a.k.a. ISO646-US, a.k.a. the Basic Latin block of the Unicode character set
>   ISO-8859-1      ISO Latin Alphabet No. 1, a.k.a. ISO-LATIN-1
>
> **UTF-8** Eight-bit UCS Transformation Format
>
> **UTF-16BE**  Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, big-endian byte order
>
> **UTF-16LE**   Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, little-endian byte order
>
> **UTF-16** Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, byte order identified by an optional byte-order mark

**Example:**

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;

String stringEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(
    "This text must be encoded! aeiou áéíóú ñ, peace!", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 3):

The usage of `org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI` is not strictly an issue; what is an issue is that you target the wrong constructor, which *is* depreciated.

Using just

```
new URI( [string] );
```

Will indeed flag it as depreciated. What is needed is to provide at minimum one additional argument (the first, below), and ideally two:

1. `escaped`: true if URI character sequence is in escaped form. false otherwise.
2. `charset`: the charset string to do escape encoding, if
   required

This will target a non-depreciated constructor within that class. So an ideal usage would be as such:

```
new URI( [string], true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString() );
```

A bit crazy-late in the game (a hair over 11 years later - *egad!*), but I hope this helps someone else, especially if the method at the far end is *still* expecting a URI, such as `org.apache.commons.httpclient.setURI()`.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter is the String to encode; the second is the name of the character encoding to use (e.g., UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

As an additional reference for the other responses, instead of using **"UTF-8"** you can use:

`HTTP.UTF_8`

which is included since Java 4 as part of the org.apache.http.protocol library, which is included also since Android API 1.

Comment: **Wrong**, this class is found in Apache HttpClient 4.x library `org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP` class.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi true, I read API 1 but it was of Android not Java, either way it exists before Java 7, it is even deprecated already haha.

Comment: no, this class **never** existed in any version of the Java JDK. Android follows the Apache HttpClient library (I won't be surprised if they took the source code from there as well).

Comment: *warning: [deprecation] UTF_8 in HTTP has been deprecated*.