# C# Uri.EscapeDatastring() equivalent for Java

Tags: c#, java, urlencode

We've implemented an HTTP authentication connection, encoded in C# with `Uri.EscapeDataString()`.

I'm trying to make an identical java test application that does the exact same thing as the C# version, but `URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8")` adds additional encoding that isn't quite the same as the C# `Uri.EscapeDataString()` function.

What's the equivalent encoding method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I've found to do this is to use the `URL.toURI().toString()` combo:

```
String uriEncodeVariable = "https://localhost:443";
URL tempURL = new URL(uriEncodeVariable);
String uriResult = tempURL.toURI().toString();
```

Comment: remember to import java.net.URL;
supported since JDK1.0 (Java 6)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not very fluent in C# but it looks like you need something like URLEncoder ? Let's have a look to SO 213506 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213506/java-net-urlencoder-encodestring-is-deprecated-what-should-i-use-instead) ?

Comment: As said in the question, using URLEncoder.encode doesn't produce the same type of encoded string.

Comment: Wow sorry fo that I was clearly not totally awake when I read your text !