# Asp.net API in Java and Android

Tags: java, android, asp.net, xml, http-get

So I am trying to contact an asp.net API that wants the parameters as an xml-string:
/v3/publicservice.asmx/GetSearchResultAdvancedXml?queryXml=**string**

http://api.tradera.com/v3/publicservice.asmx?op=GetSearchResultAdvancedXml

Thing is, I get this message:
"A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client."

Which appearantly is solved by:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2673905/585137

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

I want submit this somehow in android java with Http get.

How do I send requestValidationMode="2.0" ?

Comment: please see [Android, send and receive XML via HTTP POST method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013373/android-send-and-receive-xml-via-http-post-method) maybe help you in sending xml in request

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to scape the XML you are sending as an argument.  If you were sending the XML from another ASP.NET application, you could use: Uri.EscapeDataString.  According to this post ([C# Uri.EscapeDatastring() equivalent for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317505/c-sharp-uri-escapedatastring-equivalent-for-java)), you would have to use Java's URL or URI classes to escape a string that can later be consumed in your ASP.NET application.  But, java.net.URL and java.net.URI don't let you escape XML.  So, you could do the following:

1] Add this method to your Java code. This is a modified version of the code I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10035382/2168278.  You can, as it is suggested in the post, use an XML library.

```
public static String xmlEscapeText(String t) 
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for(int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++){
      char c = t.charAt(i);
      switch(c){
      case '<': sb.append("%3C"); break;
      case '>': sb.append("%3E"); break;
      case '\"': sb.append("%22"); break;
      case '&': sb.append("%26"); break;
      case ' ': sb.append("%20"); break;
      case '/': sb.append("%2F"); break;
      default:
         if(c>0x7e) {
            sb.append("&#"+((int)c)+";");
         }else
            sb.append(c);
      }
   }
   return sb.toString();
}
```

2] In your ASP.NET code (which I'm assuming to be C#), you can then get the XML by:

```
var myXML = Uri.UnescapeDataString(op);
```

I tested my code using this piece of XML:

```
<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
```

which I got from here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting to know what kind of string you are sending and get that issue.

This happens because of the validation introduced in ASP.NET 4 http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation which prevents cross side scripting attacks.

The configuration you saw on the other link cannot be `submiited` from android device. It needs to be done on the server side.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

[Here](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147) you can find how you can do that:

> As a result, request validation errors might now occur for requests
>   that previously did not trigger errors. To revert to the behavior of
>   the ASP.NET 2.0 request validation feature, add the following setting
>   in the **Web.config** file:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

Also, in case you want to encode the xml string you could use the simpler method in java:

```
encodedString = UrlEncoder.encode(unencodedString)
```

and decode it in C# using:

```
unencodedString = Uri.UnescapeDataString(encodedString);
```