# Java Servlet translation API request encoding problem: german characters

Tags: java, api, servlets, jakarta-ee, encoding

I have a utility class TestCracker. It has a `testInput` method that takes text, sends a request to a translating service with that text as a parameter and returns a response JSON String:

```
public class TestCracker  {
    private String ACCESS_TOKEN = "XXXXXXXXXX";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new TestCracker().testInput("Lärm"));
    }

    public String testInput(String text)  {
        String translateLink = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate" +
                "?key=" + ACCESS_TOKEN + "&text=" + text +
                "&lang=de-en" + "&format=plain" + "&options=1";

        try {
            URL translateURL = new URL(translateLink);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) translateURL.openConnection();
            setupGETConnection(connection);

            connection.connect();

            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            String inputString = new Scanner(input, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(inputString);

            return text + "; " + inputString;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't connect " + e);

            return "None";
        }
    }

    private void setupGETConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) throws Exception  {
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    }
}
```

In method `main` I tried displaying response JSON for string `Lärm`. It works fine:

```
Lärm; {"code":200,"detected":{"lang":"de"},"lang":"de-en","text":["Noise"]}
```

However, when I try to run and display the same thing using Servlet and browser, instead of just IDE:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String resultPath;
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        response.getWriter().print(request.getParameter("input-text2"));
        response.getWriter().println(new TestCracker().testInput(request.getParameter("input-text2")));
    }
}
```

When run, the `TestServlet` outputs:

```
LärmLärm; {"code":200,"detected":{"lang":"en"},"lang":"de-en","text":["L?rm"]}
```

As can be seen, the word `Lärm` was gotten from a form just fine - the first word in the response String gets displayed right (first word), the `testInput` got the right word too (second word), but the response from translation service is wrong (the part after `;`): the service couldn't translate and returned a corrupted version of the initial word: `L?rm`.

I don't understand why this happens. Where does the mistake occurs if the right word got passed to the method? And if the method when run inside IDE returns correct translation ('Noise')?

Comment: Have you tried URL encoding the text before adding it to the URL - `java.net.URLEncoder.encode(text)`? I believe it is more appropriate, even though it happens to work when run from inside the IDE.

Comment: @Nikos Paraskevopoulos It didn't seem to help ;(

Comment: @Nikos Paraskevopoulos  Another version of this method [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/213519/4759176) has worked. If you post your answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Tomcat, then the **`URIEncoding`** has to be set properly. If the parameters are on URL (GET). This must be done in the server.xml , where the connector is defined.

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="8080"/>
        <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
            <Host appBase="webapps" name="localhost"/>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

Alternatively, 
If you don't want to play around server setting, read with encoding support.

Like

```
response.getWriter()
.println(new TestCracker()
.testInput(
new String(request.getParameter("input-text2").getBytes(),"UTF-8"))
);
```

The `response.getWriter().print()` has the default `utf-8` printing capability, so you are able to see the output for that with proper character.

The first approach is better, as it will solve the issues for whole application.